# Error during runfile in Eclipse with PyDev/ error initializing console

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

Using a PyDev console in Eclipse, which initially worked fine. Python code would work inside the console.
When I started writing a file within a PyDev module, I tried executing runfile() but the console that had already initialized with python returns this error:

```
Failed to parse server's response: Expected methodResponse element, got head127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jul/2015 13:55:14] code 400, message Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('POST')
```

After which, I closed the console and restarted Eclipse. Now, when I try to even initialize the pyDev console it returns this:

```
Error initializing console.

Unexpected error connecting to console.

Failed to recive suitable Hello response from pydevconsole. Last msg received: Failed to parse server's response: Expected methodResponse element, got head
```

**Command Line used:**

C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\python.exe -u C:\Users\axelrod\Applications\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.2.0.201507041133\pysrc\pydevconsole.py 50824 50825 50824 50825

**Environment:**

PATH=C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_51/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\CREDANT\Shield v7.3\;C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda;C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Users\axelrod\Applications\eclipse;

LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local

PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6

SYSTEMDRIVE=C:

FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO

COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files

USERDOMAIN=CHAPMANEDU

LOGONSERVER=\ORDC01

LDMS_LOCAL_DIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\LANDesk\LDClient\Data

PROMPT=$P$G

SESSIONNAME=Console

ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData

PROGRAMFILES(X86)=C:\Program Files (x86)

PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64

ASL.LOG=Destination=file

DEFLOGDIR=C:\ProgramData\McAfee\DesktopProtection

WINDOWS_TRACING_FLAGS=3

PROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files

APPDATA=C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Roaming

PSMODULEPATH=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\

PROGRAMW6432=C:\Program Files

PROGRAMDATA=C:\ProgramData

SYSTEMROOT=C:\Windows

USERNAME=axelrod

VSEDEFLOGDIR=C:\ProgramData\McAfee\DesktopProtection

USERDNSDOMAIN=CHAPMAN.EDU

PYTHONPATH=C:\Users\axelrod\Applications\eclipse\plugins\org.python.pydev_4.2.0.201507041133\pysrc\pydev_sitecustomize;C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\DLLs;C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib;C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\lib-tk;C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda;C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages;C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Sphinx-1.3.1-py2.7.egg;C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\cryptography-0.9.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg;C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32;C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32\lib;C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin;C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\setuptools-17.1.1-py2.7.egg;C:\Users\axelrod\Desktop\ECLIPSE WORKSPACE\IntroPythonDataAnalysis\src

PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

OS=Windows_NT

COMPUTERNAME=ENG-AXELROD5520

COMMONPROGRAMW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files

COMMONPROGRAMFILES=C:\Program Files\Common Files

COMSPEC=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe

PROCESSOR_REVISION=2a07

CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip

WINDIR=C:\Windows

HOMEPATH=\Users\axelrod

TEMP=C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Temp

HOMEDRIVE=C:

PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel

USERPROFILE=C:\Users\axelrod

WINDOWS_TRACING_LOGFILE=C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log

TMP=C:\Users\axelrod\AppData\Local\Temp

PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public

NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4

QTJAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\QTJava.zip

PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8

PYDEV_UMD_ENABLED=true

PYDEV_UMD_NAMELIST=guidata,guiqwt

PYDEV_UMD_VERBOSE=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use Liclipse, which comes with python integration, all you have to do is to configure the interpreter. Or check weather your interpreter is configured correctly. The configuration is found at Window->Preferences->Pydev->Intrepreters. Or another thing that might be wrong is that the pydev module might be for a certain type of eclipse. I personally use LiClipse which is great.