# PyDev Interactive console not initiating

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, 64-bit, pydev

When I try to start an interactive console in Eclipse PyDev, I get the following error:

> 'Create Interactive Console' has encountered a problem.
>
> Error Initialising console.
>
> Error initializing console.
>   Unexpected error connecting to console.
>   Failed to recive suitable Hello response from pydevconsole. Last msg received: Console already exited with value: 1 while waiting for an answer.

I have already tried the following solutions given by others for similar problems to no avail:

[PyDev interactive console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355359/pydev-interactive-console)

[PyDev interactive console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355359/pydev-interactive-console/35953122#35953122)

[Pydev: error initializing console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27197887/pydev-error-initializing-console)

[Error during runfile in Eclipse with PyDev/ error initializing console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507500/error-during-runfile-in-eclipse-with-pydev-error-initializing-console)

I had had PyDev working before, but I had to upgrade my python from Python 2.7 32bit to Python 2.7 64bit to use a library developed by a colleague. I know that my Python is not the problem since this library works fine in the generic Python shell, is there something going on with my [interpreter configuration settings...?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdPvX.jpg)

I have also tried the obvious remove and reconfigure the same interpreter, which also didn't work. I'm running out of ideas, but really enjoyed using PyDev's environment, so any help - would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to alter the network settings as shown in this answer (that you already linked):
[PyDev interactive console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355359/pydev-interactive-console)

> In Eclipse under Window/Preferences/General/Network Connections:
>
> --> set Active Provider: Manual
>
> --> check in the box "Proxy bypass" if localhost and 127.0.0.1 are checked

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your python path is set in
   Window>Preferences>Interpreters>Python Interpreter

Make sure your java is 64bit

Comment: It definitely is... That was the first thing I did.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with the same issue, I ended up reinstalling everything from scratch. This was the most useful link.

http://halfanhour.blogspot.ca/2010/05/setting-up-pydev-on-eclipse-for-64-bit.html

The only thing I didn't do from this site was I downloaded the 64 bit Neon that was offered. I guess back when that posting was written, the 64 bit was not a good version.

This was annoying and nothing out there seemed to help, but it now works.